# Задать формат вывода в функции cat в R

Tags: r

Вывожу в текстовый файл вектор вот такой командой:

```
cat(vector, file="vector.txt", sep = "\r\n")
```

Выводятся числа *double* с фиксированным числом знаков после запятой (типа *0.0000*). Как вывести числа в экспоненциальном формате (типа *0.000E-00*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией `format()` с аргументом `scientific = TRUE`.

```
x <- runif(10, 1e-06, 0.1)
cat(x, file = "")
#> 0.09239792 0.0301293 0.04420677 0.05487988 0.02007459 0.07610528 0.04467654 0.0819289 0.02348505 0.01109257
cat(format(x, scientific = TRUE), file = "")
#> 9.239792e-02 3.012930e-02 4.420677e-02 5.487988e-02 2.007459e-02 7.610528e-02 4.467654e-02 8.192890e-02 2.348505e-02 1.109257e-02
```

Для изменения поведения по умолчанию можно установить опцию `scipen`:

```
options(scipen = -4)
cat(x, file = "")
#> 2.909247e-02 8.975441e-02 5.346754e-02 8.321206e-02 2.835869e-02 7.648233e-02 9.343155e-02 5.415266e-02 2.031097e-02 7.296047e-02
```

Подробнее по опциям R смотрите справку : `help("options")`.

Выдержка относительно `scipen`:

> integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider.